# Dynamically setting the sortable property of a kendo grid column

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I'm trying to set a kendo grid column's `sortable` property via a variable to control when the column can have sorting facility and when it can't.
But this is not working.
If I directly set the `sortable` property to `true`/`false` it works accordingly, but when I'm using a variable to set it, it is not, regardless of the variable value, the property is always set to 'true'.

#### Example:

This works as expected.

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { sortable: false, field: "id" },
    { field: "name" }
  ],
  sortable: true,
  dataSource: [ { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe" }, { id: 2, name: "John Doe" } ]
});
</sript>
```

But this does not, `id` field always gets `sortable` property as `true`

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
// if first time it's true, then the sortable property is retaining true always, 
// regardless if on second call the variable is set to false. there is no effect
var setColumnSort = canBeFalseOrTrue;
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { sortable: setColumnSort, field: "id" },
    { field: "name" }
  ],
  sortable: true,
  dataSource: [ { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe" }, { id: 2, name: "John Doe" } ]
});
</script>
```

Is there anyway to dynamically disable/enable sorting of a column in a kendo grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it dynamically through grid properties once the grid is initialized.

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
  sortable: true,
  columns: [
    {...}
  ]
});

var grid = $('#grid').getKendoGrid();

var options = grid.options;
options.columns[0].sortable = false;
grid.setOptions(options);
```

Example: [Enable/disable sorting on column](https://dojo.telerik.com/ixeyUBUS)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked perfectly. 
In my application the grid has like 80 plus columns and developers can add new columns in the grid anywhere as per requirement. so instead of `fixed column index` I got the `index` from `column field name`.

Comment: Here is what I did
`function DisbaleSort(){
 var columnsToModifySort = ["field1", "field2"];
 var grid = $('#grid').getKendoGrid();
 var options = grid.options;
 var columns = options.columns;

 _.each(columnsToModifySort, function (fieldName) {
  var index = columns.findIndex(function (v, i) { return grid.columns[i].field === fieldName; });
  if (index >= 0) {
   columns[index].sortable = false;
   grid.setOptions(options);
  }
 });
}`